# Daemonize web.py python application in Debian 6.06

Tags: python, jenkins, debian, daemon

I am trying to daemonize a web.py python application in debian 6.06 so that I can start / stop it with jenkins.

The most progress I have made so far is this:

```
root@ip-10-80-227-164:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta# /sbin/start-stop-daemon 
--start --pidfile /var/tmp/betad/betad.pid --user root --group root 
--exec /usr/local/bin/python2.7 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/beta/app.py --verbose
```

but that breaks all of the relative paths inside the application. I get a stack trace like

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './somefile'
```

Normally I start the server with `python app.py` and it runs without issue.

I would love to daemonize it like [pep 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) but I don't know how I would tell it to run app.py in daemon context (the application isn't wrapped in a function I can call).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can't you wrap the daemon around the `app.run()` call?

Comment: Yes thank you! Wow i'm out of it today. Also, this is awesome: http://edvanbeinum.com/how-to-install-and-configure-supervisord

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this: http://edvanbeinum.com/how-to-install-and-configure-supervisord I can easily do it with supervisord